# AngularJS Controller As: Promise not updating view

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Been banging my head against a wall trying to figure out how `controller as` and Promises work together with AngularJS. It seems that by wrapping a result in a promise, AngularJS does not see the controller updating until you trigger a different change.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="MainModule" ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
        <h1 class="title">Test Bench</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="app">
        <h1>Test Bench</h1>

        <div class="text-center">
            <p>Last Fingerprint Result: {{main.lastAuthSuccessful}}</p>
        </div>
.....
</body>
```

The controller method in question:

```
doFingerprint() {
    this.auth
      .fingerprint()

      .then(success => {
        console.log(this, self, this.self);
        this.lastAuthSuccessful = success;
      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        return false;
      });
  }
```

And the fingerprint method in the auth service:

```
fingerprint(): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!this.finger) return Promise.reject("Fingerprint API not yet loaded.");

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.finger.show(
        {
          clientId: "Fingerprint-Demo",
          clientSecret: "password"
        },

        () => {
          resolve(true);
        },

        err => {
          resolve(false);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

This feels pretty straightforward, but the updated `lastAuthSuccessful` from the promise refuses to update the view until you attempt to call the method again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has its own Promise implementation, which is [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).
The ES6 Promise won't trigger Angular's digest cycle, you should use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) instead.

If you insist using ES6 Promise, you can call $scope.$apply().
$apply() is used to execute an expression in AngularJS from outside of the AngularJS framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third-party libraries).

Usually, you **don't** call $digest() directly in controllers or in directives. Instead, you should call $apply() (typically from within a directive), which will force a $digest().

```
fingerprint(): Promise<boolean> {
    let deferred = $q.defer();
    if (!this.finger) return $q.reject("Fingerprint API not yet loaded.");

    this.finger.show(
        {
          clientId: "Fingerprint-Demo",
          clientSecret: "password"
        },

        () => {
          deferred.resolve(true);
        },

        err => {
          deferred.resolve(false);
        }
      );

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

angular.js famously (or rather infamously) uses [the digest loop](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/) for change detection. Builtin angular directives like `ng-click` will call `$scope.$digest()` for you, but here your change is being made asynchronously, when the promise resolves, and no one calls `$digest()`.

So, you can either call `$scope.$digest()` yourself in the `then` block of the promise, or you can use the [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), which is angular's implementation of Promises, where it calls `$digest` for you.